# C++ on Windows: executable path with whitespace in system() call

Tags: c++, windows

I am trying to execute a file with parameters using the "system()" function in C++ on Windows, and it works as long as there are no whitespaces in the filename. For parameters, putting double quotes around the string works, but when I try the same with the executable itself, I get the following error:

"the filename,directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect"

Does anyone know how to handle this correctly?

Comment: Could you post your code relevant to the question? Maybe we can spot a mistake there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a string like this:

`cmd /S /C "your entire command line string"`

See: [How do I deal with quote characters when using cmd.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355988/how-do-i-deal-with-quote-characters-when-using-cmd-exe)

Answer (score 0):

It should work, look for the problem elsewhere.

Perhaps something in your flow is removing the whitespace or the double quotes from the string.