# string format in c# running command line

Tags: c#, string, command-line

If I run following command in console, it will succeed:

```
"C:\Users\myAccount.Unit\Favorites\Downloads\fiji.app (1)\fiji.exe" -macro "C:\Users\myAccount.Unit\Favorites\Downloads\fiji.app (1)\macros\FFTBatch.ijm" C:\Users\myAccount.Unit\Documents\Untitled001\
```

where
 `"C:\Users\myAccount.Unit\Favorites\Downloads\fiji.app (1)\fiji.exe"` is the application file,

`"C:\Users\myAccount.Unit\Favorites\Downloads\fiji.app (1)\macros\FFTBatch.ijm"` is the macro file that gets executed,

and `C:\Users\myAccount.Unit\Documents\Untitled001\` is the images processed by the previous macro.

However, when I use C# to do this job, it failed (meaning no response at all). Following is the relevant code:

```
string _fijiExeFile = "C:\\Users\\myAccount.Unit\\Favorites\\Downloads\\fiji.app (1)\\fiji.exe";
string _ijmFile = "C:\\Users\\myAccount.Unit\\Favorites\\Downloads\\fiji.app (1)\\macros\\FFTBatch.ijm";
string _inputDir = "C:\\Users\\myAccount.Unit\\Documents\\Untitled001\\";
string fijiCmdText = string.Format("/C \"{0}\" -macro \"{1}\" {2}", _fijiExeFile, _ijmFile, _inputDir);

try
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    startInfo.Arguments = fijiCmdText;
    process.StartInfo = startInfo;
    process.Start();
    _processOn = true;
    process.WaitForExit();

    ret = 1;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    ret = 0;
}
```

**(The path are actually obtained from the UI, I am just posting what it is.)**

This is what I observed for `fijiCmdText` when I step in:

```
"/C \"C:\\Users\\myAccount.Unit\\Favorites\\Downloads\\fiji.app (1)\\fiji.exe\" -macro \"C:\\Users\\myAccount.Unit\\Favorites\\Downloads\\fiji.app (1)\\macros\\FFTBatch.ijm\" C:\\Users\\myAccount.Unit\\Documents\\Untitled001\\"
```

If I only use

```
string fijiCmdText = string.Format("/C \"{0}\"", _fijiExeFile);
```

It does launch the .exe application, however if I intended to add the macro file path, it fails.

Any thing wrong here?

Comment: Yes. Don't ever ignore exceptions. At least display `ex.ToString()` so that you can know what's going wrong.

Comment: @JohnSaunders It does not go to exceptions.

Comment: If I step in and it did not hit the catch?

Comment: I would get the value of `fijiCmdText` then try to run from an actual command line.

Comment: I pasted the actual value of fijiCmdText, I cannot see anything wrong?

Comment: Not sure if this is the issue, but open a command prompt, type "cmd.exe /?" and read the part on quotes.

Comment: It works when there is no macro path involved. basically, fijiCmdText = string.Format("/C \"{0}\"", _fijiExeFile); works

Comment: Here's your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/355988/how-do-i-deal-with-quote-characters-when-using-cmd-exe

Comment: @JohnnyMopp I am sorry I am not an English speaker, so I am not sure if I extract information from your link correctly. How do I change the command line as the thread pointed out? like /S /C? It did not work.

Comment: It also does not make sense why it worked when there is no macro path, because if you noticed the .exe file path contains space.

Comment: @NickXTsui , you should make it work directly through command line first, then if working you can worry about C#

Comment: It does work in the command line. It is just the formatting issue which is exactly what I am asking here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link I posted states that you need to use the /S switch **and** put the entire command in quotes:

```
string fijiCmdText = string.Format("/S /C \"\"{0}\" -macro \"{1}\" {2}\"", _fijiExeFile, _ijmFile, _inputDir);
```

Or, more clearly:

```
string fijiCmdText = "/S /C \"<command line that can have quotes>\"";
```

Comment: Yes worked. It is the \" in front of the \"{0}\" that solves the whole problem. Care to explain a little why? or a link to explain this? Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: I think that means deliminate the whole command line instead of processing them individually.