# Start process with parameter

Tags: c#

You can use this command to start FreePascal from Command Prompt with a source to load: **C:\FPC\2.6.2\bin\i386-win32\fp.exe 2.pas**, where the first argument is the path to the FreePascal executable and 2.pas is a source. Now, I want to open sources like this from C#. I already tried this but didn't work:

```
Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false; //required to redirect
startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = string.Format("/C C:\\FPC\\2.6.2\\bin\\i386-win32\\fp.exe \"{0}\"", sourcePath);

process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
```

And

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = "C:\\FPC\\2.6.2\\bin\\i386-win32\\fp.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = path;
Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Do you have any suggestion?
Thank you!

UPDATE
Example of path value:
"C:\FPC\2.6.2\bin\i386-win32\3.pas"

Comment: What's the value of `path` (in the second example - which is the right way to do it)? Does it have any spaces in it?

Comment: Clearly `path` contains relative path and as result file will not be opened after fixing path to exe... If it is not true - please make sure to update post with exact value of the `path`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21564532/string-format-in-c-sharp-running-command-line/21580241#21580241

Comment: Updated. I tried with the S/ prefix but didn't worked. With the first block of code the window is opening, the source is loaded, but I can't interact with the program. It's like a picture. Wherever I click or press a key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding an `@` to your string, making it a [verbatim string literal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), so the backslashes are left alone:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = @"C:\FPC\2.6.2\bin\i386-win32\fp.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = path;
Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Or:

```
startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = string.Format("/C {0} \"{1}\"",
    @"C:\FPC\2.6.2\bin\i386-win32\fp.exe", sourcePath);
```

Comment: @Alex - If the string is good, then your question contains a typo.  Backslash is the escape character.  You need to either escape it (with double backslashes: `"C:\\dir"`) or use a verbatim string literal (`@"C:\dir"`).  If your code accounts for that already, you should correct the code in your question.

Comment: You are right. The program has the path correctly saved and is building the path. This is the code actually. I tried to simplify for the question:           startInfo.Arguments = string.Format(@"/S /C {0}\\fp.exe ""{1}""", Settings.FpcInstallationFolder.TrimEnd('\\'), path);

Answer (score 1):

You have to prepend the path strings with `@`. Please follow the code below:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = @"C:\FPC\2.6.2\bin\i386-win32\fp.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = @"2.pas";
Process.Start(startInfo);
```