# How to filter the first 1 Sec of a Pcap file with Tshark in C#?

Tags: cmd, filtering, pcap, tshark

I have a small problem with filtering the first 1 second of a Pcap file and export it Via C# command. The command below execute just fine in CMD:

```
c:\Program Files\Wireshark\tshark.exe -r  10Secfile.pcap -T fields -E separator=, -E quote=d -e wlan_mgt.fixed.timestamp -e radiotap.mactime -e wlan_mgt.ssid -e radiotap.dbm_antsignal -e wlan.fc.type_subtype -R "frame.time_relative <=1.0" >> 1SecFile.txt
```

But when I try to do the exact same thing in C# like this:

```
strCmdText = "/C \"c:\\Program Files\\Wireshark\\tshark.exe\" -r 10SecFile.pcap -T fields -E separator=, -E quote=d -e wlan_mgt.fixed.timestamp -e radiotap.mactime -e wlan_mgt.ssid -e radiotap.dbm_antsignal -e wlan.fc.type_subtype -R \"frame.time_relative <=1.0\" >> 1SecFile.txt";
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
process.StartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("CMD.exe", strCmdText);
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();
```

I get this error: "the system cannot find the file specified command". And I am sure that all the paths to executables are found because the code works as soon as I remove the last filter:

```
 -R \"frame.time_relative <=1.0\"
```

I even placed a breakpoint after "strCmdText=" and copied the value of it manually and pasted it into CMD and it works just fine.

I really appreciate if you help me to figure this out.

Comment: Seems like the extra indirection with `cmd /c` removes the quotes around `"frame.time_relative <=1.0"` which makes the "<=1.0" an input redirection to a "=1.0" file which, of course, doesn't exists. Try getting it right on the command line with `cmd /c`, you probably need to use extra quotes, then "import" the command into your c# program once it's working.

Comment: Thanks @Guntram, that's exactly the problem I have tried using extra quotes around the filter and still gives me the same error.

Answer (score 0):

First I would like to thank @Guntram Blohm for the small but great tip which gave me the lead to go and search new topics.
[I found this topic which explained my exact problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355988/how-do-i-deal-with-quote-characters-when-using-cmd-exe)

So it's as Simple as adding

> /S

Before "/C". I can not believe that everything works perfect now. The edited line is as follow:

```
cmd /S /C "Rest of your code/Command here"
```

Thanks a lot!