# Reading White Space in File Path

Tags: java, file, path

I have code which has to read a bat file and run it. But path contains Space how we can read space in java in file path. Below is the code

```
   String cmd5 = "cmd /c start E://Test 1.4.3/start.bat";
    Process p5 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd5);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
String cmd5 = "cmd /c \"E:\\Test 1.4.3\\start.bat\""
```

see: [How do I deal with quote characters when using cmd.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355988/how-do-i-deal-with-quote-characters-when-using-cmd-exe)

Comment: it does not run my actual bat file

Answer (score 0):

You can try quotes around it

```
String cmd5 = "cmd.exe /c start \"E:/Test 1.4.3/start.bat\"";
Process p5 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd5);
```

or a string array

```
String[] cmd5s = { "cmd.exe", "/c", "start", "E:/Test 1.4.3/start.bat" };
Process p5 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd5s);
```

For the rest **ProcessBuilder** is nicer in usage than **Runtime**.