# C# Process removes quoted arguments

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

The command I'm trying to execute is

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\MyAPP\solr-6.2.0\bin\solr" start -f -c -z "10.195.42.93:2181,10.195.42.92:2181" -h 10.195.42.92

And this **works just fine on the command Line**.

I'm trying to execute this as C# process.

NOTE: **Below code works fine if i remove the quotes surrounding IPList**

```
var IPList="10.195.42.93:2181,10.195.42.92:2181";
var hostIP="10.195.42.92"

string command = @"/c ""C:\Program Files (x86)\MyApp\solr-6.2.0\bin\solr"" start -f -c -z """ + IPList + @""" -h " + hostIP;
Process process = new Process();
log.Info("Starting " + command);
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = command;
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
process.OutputDataReceived += (s, e) => log.Info(e.Data);
process.ErrorDataReceived += (s, e) => log.Info(e.Data);
process.Start();
process.BeginOutputReadLine();
process.BeginErrorReadLine();
```

This throws error :

> 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,...

I have looked at the similar issue posted [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355988/how-do-i-deal-with-quote-characters-when-using-cmd-exe) and tried the *`/s`* option but no heed. 
What am i missing here ?

Comment: Why don't you put the command  arguments in the [ProcessStartInfo.Arguments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.arguments(v=vs.110).aspx) property?

Comment: The command which is working on command line doesn't have anything like `/c` but in code your command starts with `/c` which is actually looks like a command line parameter.

Comment: Yes @RBT, Its a option of cmd.exe. /C  Carries out the command specified by string and then terminates.

Comment: Why the down Vote ? Wow, Did this piece of code work for you as expected? If so please share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enclosing the command with "(quotes) after /c solves the issue.

Example :

> "/c **"**"c:\prog files\xyz\solr" start -c -z "blah,blah,blah" -h
>   IP **"**

Basically the command that is getting executed is

```
> cmd.exe /c "C:\Program Files (x86)\MyAPP\solr-6.2.0\bin\solr" start -f -c -z "10.195.42.93:2181,10.195.42.92:2181" -h 10.195.42.92
```

This command fails, and this has nothing to do with c# process api or .net.

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, it is trying to execute C:\Program which basically means something is wrong with the way you are escaping quotes. May be try to escape " using - \"

Answer (score 0):

You're asking `cmd.exe` to run the command `C:\Program Files (x86)\MyApp\solr-6.2.0\bin\solr`. It will *not* run `"C:\Program Files (x86)\MyApp\solr-6.2.0\bin\solr"` because the quotes are consumed by the invocation of `cmd.exe`.

I do not know the proper way to fix this. You probably need to add escaped quotes somehow.