# Running and saving command output using VBA

Tags: vba, cmd, io-redirection, wsh

I am trying to run shell commands from VBA and get output into a csv file. Below is the code I am using:

```
Dim wsh as Object
Set wsh = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")  
plink_path="C:\plink.exe"
key_path="putty key path"
pass_query="select * from test"
command1 = Replace(plink_path & " hadoop@11.11.11.11 -i " & key_path & " mysql -uuser -ppass -e 'use radar;" & pass_query & "'", Chr(10), " ")
wsh.Run command1 & ">E:/anurag.csv", 0, True
```

But I am not able to view output file in the E drive.  When I run the above command manually from a `cmd` prompt I do get an output in the E drive.

Comment: If it sends output to STDOUT, [something like this might](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cbxxzwb5(v=vs.84).aspx) be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two thoughts:

1. Try `E:\anurag.csv` instead of `E:/anurag.csv`
2. Use `cmd` to invoke `plink`, since `cmd` usually processes the redirections.  Replace the `wsh.Run` line with:

   ```
   command1 = command1 & ">E:\anurag.csv"
   command1 = "cmd /c """ & command1 & """"
   wsh.Run command1, 0, True
   ```

   The first line completes the command you wanted to execute and the second wraps it in a `cmd /c` call.

   - If this doesn't work, try changing `/c` above to `/c /s` per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/356014/2877364).

YMMV - not tested

Comment: It worked perfectly when i used command1 = "cmd /c """ & command1 & """".Thumbs up for that.