# Correct way of quoting following command line

Tags: c#, command-line, command-line-arguments, command-pattern

How should I quote following command to get desired output -

```
cmd.exe /c "C:\Remote\Remote.exe -u somedomain\Administrator -p i4D4KuHb0KTcpXObqf49ZbopthoFkC+yUYbkY6srPJ4= -util "C:\Program Files\V\Nt\bin\spprt\u.exe" -output winmas02_2018-12-18__12-23-37  -odir "C:\Program Files\Vx\NB\bin\spprt\winmas02_2018-12-18__12-23-37""
```

Here `Remote.exe` is C#.NET command application. `-u -p -output -odir` are getting passed to this (Remote.exe) correctly. `Remote.exe` is responsible to start `u.exe` under the impersonated context of give user credentials. I am using .net's Process and ProcessStartInfo classes here.`u.exe`is legacy non .net application

The current behavior -

`Remote.exe` is successfully launching `u.exe` however the quoted path passed to `-odir` parameter for `u.exe` is not working. 'u.exe' is failing because the path passed to `-odir` parameter is breaking at `"C:\Program "`

Any pointer on how to handle this?

Comment: Unless there are special characters (`&<>()@^|`) between the enclosing quotes, inner quotes [should be preserved](https://stackoverflow.com/q/355988/69809), but you need to specify the `/s` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try -

cmd.exe /c "C:\Remote\Remote.exe" -u somedomain\Administrator -p "i4D4KuHb0KTcpXObqf49ZbopthoFkC+yUYbkY6srPJ4=" -util "C:\Program Files\V\Nt\bin\spprt\u.exe" -output "winmas02_2018-12-18__12-23-37"  -odir "C:\Program Files\Vx\NB\bin\spprt\winmas02_2018-12-18__12-23-37"